# Python: Replacing NaN in a specific column by values from another dataframe after matching values in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, nan

Assume I have df1:

```
    series_id       hour       temp       angle
0   001             12         NaN        130
1   001             11         16         149
2   002             12         18.9       128
3   002             13         20         NaN
4   003             13         NaN        NaN
5   003             11         NaN        97
6   003             12         17.3       216
```

& df2:

```
    hour      temp
0   11          17
1   12          15
2   13          16
```

What I wish to do here is to replace the NA values in 'temp' column in df1 with values from df2 where values of 'hour' column in df1 matches with that in df2's. Desired outcome of df1:

```
    series_id       hour       temp       angle
0   001             12         15         130
1   001             11         16         149
2   002             12         18.9       128
3   002             13         20         NaN
4   003             13         16         NaN
5   003             11         17         97
6   003             12         17.3       216
```

I'm new to Python & am not familiar with this language's syntax. Any advice on this?

Extra: The equivalent of what I want in R would be

```
df1$temp <- ifelse(is.na(df1$temp), df2$temp[match(df1$hour, df2$hour)], df1$temp)
```

Here's the code I used to create the two dataframes in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

df1 = {'series_id' : ['001','001','002','002','003','003','003'],
       'hour' : [12,11,12,13,13,11,12],
       'temp' : [np.nan, 16, 18.9, 20, np.nan, np.nan, 17.3],
       'angle' : [130,149,128, np.nan, np.nan,97,216]}
df2 = {'hour' : [11,12,13],
       'temp' : [17,15,16]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['series_id', 'hour', 'temp', 'angle'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = ['hour', 'temp'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1['temp'] = df1['temp'].fillna(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='hour', how='left')['temp_y'])
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
  series_id  hour  temp  angle
0       001    12  15.0  130.0
1       001    11  16.0  149.0
2       002    12  18.9  128.0
3       002    13  20.0    NaN
4       003    13  16.0    NaN
5       003    11  17.0   97.0
6       003    12  17.3  216.0
```

Comment: Another alternative is `map` `df1['temp'].fillna(df1['hour'].map(df2.set_index('hour')['temp']))` ;)